# i could not get an output after ./a.out in c++ even in simple hello program

Tags: c++

i write the simple hello program.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 cout<<"hello";
}
```

and I compile the program as `g++ hello.cpp` and run it as`./a.out` but could not get output as hello

Comment: Try adding a new line character, to flush the buffer. `cout<<"hello"<<endl;`

Comment: no i get just terminal omkar$

Comment: ohh yeah ..i got it thanx alexander

Comment: i don't konw much about c++ user2079303 so i just tagged it..

Comment: I assume that you overlooked that your prompt is `helloomkar$` ;-)

Comment: @OmkarWaghe I see. C++cli is another language and unless you know that you wrote your pgoram in c++-cli, then you probably didn't.

Comment: no i looked it ..it's only problem with 'endl'.

Comment: Can you add an exact transcript of your terminal output to the question please? Including the lines where you build and attempt to run, and including all output.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara a new line character won't flush the buffer (but `endl` will). But the flushing shouldn't be needed unless the program crashes, because the stream will be flushed at the end of the program anyway.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - to add a new line character use `'\n'`. To start a new line and force an unnecessary (in this case) flush, use `std::endl`.

Comment: @user2079303 Well with g++ and outputting to a terminal (not redirecting), `std::cout` is line buffered anyway.

Comment: @user2079303 Yeah, I know. The important thing here is the new line so the prompt will not overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

The sample provide should work and should produce output. I do not see a reason not to print output. You could try flushing the std output stream and see whether it makes any difference. If you are running the program on a Linux platform, then you can debug using strace and there should be a write system call at the end.

strace a.out

Example:
....
write(1, "hello", 5hello)                    = 5

exit_group(0)                           = ?

Comment: I suspect this is a much simpler problem about not actually building or running the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

## You have output.

You just didn't add a newline character. It worked, but you probably saw something like as follows where your normal prompt was:

```
hello$
```

If you change `std::cout << "hello";` to `std::cout << "hello\n";`, it'll "work" as expected.

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't say it didn't. It doesn't automatically add a newline.